# jquery submit form show the whole html as result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, loader

I have a search form with a submit button that show results from database.

I want to show loader, with delay 2s before showing the results

The problem is that results show the whole html page with the result, not only the result div.

The code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $("#search").ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#login_result").html("<div id='wrapper'><div class='cssload-loader text-center'></div></div><p>Loading...</p>");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#results").html(data);
                },2000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My result code in:

```
<div class="container bootstrap snippet "  id="results" style="margin-bottom: 90px;">
        <div class="row">
        <div id="login_result"></div>

        <!-- results HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Search form code:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p style="font-family: 'rawy-bold';font-size:35px;color:white;margin-top:20px;">
        Search
    </p>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" class="form-inline" id="search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchinput" size="50">
        <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-danger">search</button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: #login_result where is that

Comment: So your AJAX call is returning what HTML? Containing the results?

Comment: you indicate where you want the result to be put in the row, that is inside the container that is inside the results div. But your code adds data to the #result div ? Is this intentional that you overwrite the container and row div ?

Comment: @ImranAhmadShahid i fixed the code it is in result code

Comment: @lumio result contain the whole HTML page including navbar search form and results

Comment: You nead to post the result you get, so we can help your parse out what you need form the entire result.

Comment: $("#results").html(data); Here data is a variable that receives your result, and contains your result. So you must parse this data. If you post the content of this, we can help you write code to extract only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you need to do is to parse the resulting HTML. Then you parse and find the wrapping element that is around your results. In this example here I assumed it is something like `<div class="result-wrapper"><!-- your results --></div>`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $("#search").ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#login_result").html("<div id='wrapper'><div class='cssload-loader text-center'></div></div><p>Loading...</p>");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Parse and find element
                    var result = $( data ).find( '.result-wrapper' );
                    $("#results").html( result.html() );
                },2000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply fixed this with changing the form `action="index.php"` to `action="results.php"` and i moved my result code to `results.php` page.
It Worked! so when I submit the form and have success; `$("#results").html(data);` will print the data from `results.php` not from `index.php`..